# limit at infinity quotient by x privided given function uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose $f(x)$ is real valued uniformly  continuous function on $ \mathbb R$. Is it true that limit of $f(x)/x$ exists as x tends to infinity and minus infinity?

Comment: No if function is x then limit will be 1

Comment: That's correct.  My mistake.  We must have $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(|x|)$ . So $f(x)/x$ is always bounded and question remains if limit always exists.

Comment: Now I can reopen the question, but I should tell you that problem statement questions like this (no effort / no context) are typically closed. Did you read the site info on how to ask a good question?

Comment: I would suggest to consider the function $$ f(x) = x \sin(\log(1+|x|)) $$